# Unable to bypass an endpoint from spring security if calling a repo method in which I'm creating a native query and dynamically binding params

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

I am able to successfully bypass an endpoint from spring security by passing it as regex param to antMatchers of overridden configure method

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
```

But unfortunately, the endpoint identified by regex remains by-passed as long as I don't make any customRepoImpl call in the servieImpl which my controller calls. It works fine if I make repo call to a simple repo like

```java
@Repository
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Spv, Long>
```

But as soon as I make a repo call to customRepoImpl (in which I have a parameterized native query and dynamically bind params), strangely the endpoint starts complaining that full authentication is required, and if I comment the line in which I'm making the repo call, it again starts working like a charm - i.e. w/o having to pass a bearer-token in Authorization header, I'm able to hit the end point.

How can I fix this.

Here's my SecurityConfiguration class.

```java
@Configuration
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**", "/test/**")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
        http.cors();
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/upload/**").antMatchers("/upload/**").antMatchers("/uploadmedia/**")
                .antMatchers("/transcoder/decrypt/**").antMatchers("/download/**").antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")
                // swagger-docs
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
                // swagger-ui
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
                // swagger-ui
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")
                .antMatchers("/test/**")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                ;
    }
```

Here's my Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/test-a-method")
    public void test_method() {
        testService.test();
    }

}
```

Here's my ServiceImpl

```java
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Autowired
    ContractMappingCustomRepo repo;

    @Autowired
    TestRepo testRepo;

    @Override
    public void test() {

        List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.add(319L);
        ids.add(320L);
        ids.add(321L);
        
        //If I comment lines identified below,
        //and make call to just testRepo which extends JpaRepo, 
        //bypassing of end-point works fine.
        
        // --- If I comment these 5 lines of code, works fine
        List<Object[]> contractMapping = new ArrayList<>();
        contractMapping = repo.getContractMapping(ids);

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

        contractMapping.stream()
                .forEach(x -> stringList.add(x[0].toString()) );

        stringList.forEach(x-> System.out.println(x));
        //--- above 5 lines are culprit, esp the one with repo.getContractMapping(ids)

        List<Spv> all = testRepo.findAll();
        all.forEach(x-> System.out.println(x.getSpvLanguages()));

    }
}
```

Here's my suspicious method

```java
@Override
    public List<Object[]> getContractMapping(List<Long> idList) {
        //1. Generate parameterized sql string
        String sql = "select distinct contractMapping from contract_details where  JSON_EXTRACT(contractMapping,\"$.level1.id\") in ( " + Constants.ID_1 + "," + Constants.ID_2 + "," + Constants.ID_3 + " ) and " +
                "configuredInWf = 0 and contractId in ( :idList ) ";

        //2. Create parameterized native query
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);

        //3. Bind parameters (from method arguments into the parameterized native query)
        query.setParameter("idList", idList);

        //4. Return query.getResultList()
        List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
```

Here's my test repo

```java
@Repository
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Spv, Long> {

}
```

NB: I'm aware that suspicious method isn't the optimal way to write the query. I myself use JPQL. However, this is the way it's currently implemented and causing issues. Please try to address why with this repo implementation spring won't let me bypass security for my /test-a-method endpoint. I can optimize my repo myself later on. Thanks.

Also, I can't share whole of my code-base.
There are much complicated repos whose controllers I need to bypass but I can't share them here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I get the inability to post a whole code base, can you give us a small GitHub repo that demonstrates your issue, I honestly am having some trouble following the need.

Comment: okay, i'll create a new repo and share with you so you can easily run for yourself and see. But since it's friday night, I'll be able to share it in a few days time. Also, really surprised by non-deterministic behaviour of spring-security. Thanks again @fpmoles not just for your course on linked in but for being active member in your city and also online. \/,